# Why google rejected my app with "Please change your metadata to explain that your app uses a third party"

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, intentfilter

I can't understand why my app has been rejected from the playstore with that reason :

> Please change your metadata to explain that your app uses a third
>   party barcode scanner to function. Changing your metadata will keep
>   your app on the store.

My app uses intent-filters to run another app, scan a barcode, and get this barcode back.

I have follow the Android documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters to configure my manifest.

What's wrong, please anyone has an idea ?

Comment: You should try to get direct support from Google by using the chat or email contact in the developer console, they may be able to explain the reason. Would be good if you post the reason once you find it out. By the way, what I can't understand is if you already had some text in your store description stating that you are using a barcode scanner or not (?). Although, the fact that if an app uses a barcode scanner then it must explain it in the description is actually very surprising.

Comment: Maybe the issue isn't about the barcode scanner at all, but about the fact that in order for your app to function correctly it requires a third-party app, in this case a barcode scanner? Just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it has been rejected, as I can't find a reference anywhere about that on Play Policy. However, the recommended way to do barcode scanning for Android I think is now to use [ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes) so you might want to consider that, then you won't need for your users to have another app installed.

Comment: Useful tip, but not an answer to his question. Should be a comment